# UTF8 to Base 2 Representation Swift

Tags: swift, binary, radix, utf

I was wondering what is the best way for converting an UTF8 Array or String to its base 2 representation(each UTF8 value of each character to its base 2 representation) . Since you could have two values representing the code for the same character, I suppose extracting values from the array and then converting it is not a valid method. So which one is? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible  approach:

- Enumerate the unicode scalars of the string.
- Convert each unicode scalar back to a string, and enumerate its
  UTF-8 encoding.
- Convert each UTF-8 byte to a "binary string".

The last task can be done with the following generic method which
works for all unsigned integer types:

```
extension UnsignedIntegerType {
    func toBinaryString() -> String {
        let s = String(self, radix: 2)
        let numBits = 8 * sizeofValue(self)
        return String(count: numBits - s.characters.count, repeatedValue: Character("0")) + s
    }
}

// Example:
// UInt8(100).toBinaryString() = "01100100"
// UInt16.max.toBinaryString() = "1111111111111111"
```

Then the conversion to a UTF-8 binary representation can be 
implemented like this:

```
func binaryUTF8Strings(string: String) -> [String] {
    return string.unicodeScalars.map {
        String($0).utf8.map { $0.toBinaryString() }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
for u in base2UTF8("H€llö ") {
    print(u)
}
```

Output:

```
01001000
11100010 10000010 10101100
01101100
01101100
11000011 10110110
00100000
11110000 10011111 10000111 10101001
11110000 10011111 10000111 10101010
```

Note that "" is a single character (an "extended grapheme cluster")
but *two* unicode scalars.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the most logical approach I've seen on this subject!